# Work with xml in postgresql?

Tags: xml, database, postgresql, psql

I have a xml document. Put it into posgresql table.
This is the way i put it.

```
create or replace function bytea_import(p_path text, p_result out bytea) 
                   language plpgsql as $$
declare
  l_oid oid;
  r record;
begin
  p_result := '';
  select lo_import(p_path) into l_oid;
  for r in ( select data 
             from pg_largeobject 
             where loid = l_oid 
             order by pageno ) loop
    p_result = p_result || r.data;
  end loop;
  perform lo_unlink(l_oid);
end;$$;


 insert into mydocs(docform,content)
 values (3, convert_from(bytea_import('D:/html/ex08.xml'), 'utf-8'));
```

I need to change document. For example

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<list_of_items>
<item id="1"><first/>first</item>
<item id="2">second <sub_item>subsecond 1</sub_item></item>
<item id="3">third</item>
<item id="4"><last/>last</item>
</list_of_items>
```

Have to take out text from this document and put into other table:

`first` put into column 1  of table 2

`second` put into column 2  of table 2

`subsecond` put into column 3 of table 2

`third` put into column 4 of table 2

`last`put into column 5 of table 2

Gab made a good answer, but i have 1 more question.
How to made it for any kind of xml.
how to delete rows like

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<list_of_items>
</list_of_items>
```

and choose any text, without `xpath` search?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won the hardest question of the day. Get an upvote for it!

With the following query:

```
WITH x(col) AS (
    SELECT '<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <list_of_items>
    <item id="1"><first/>first</item>
    <item id="2">second <sub_item>subsecond 1</sub_item></item>
    <item id="3">third</item>
    <item id="4"><last/>last</item>
    </list_of_items>
    '::xml
), interpreted as (
    SELECT xpath('.//item/text()', col) AS val,
           xpath('.//sub_item/text()', col) AS val2
    FROM   x
)
SELECT val[1] as col1, val[2] as col2, val2[1] as col3, val[3] as col4, val[4] as col5
FROM interpreted
;
```

You can get:

```
 col1  |  col2   |    col3     | col4  | col5 
-------+---------+-------------+-------+------
 first | second  | subsecond 1 | third | last
(1 row)
```

Comment: "I don't make enough money for this s***"

Comment: it could be made only this way? 
is there some common or general way for all kind of xml?

Comment: What do you mean? It is a simple solution that does exactly what you asked for. Its fairly generic